# CRM 2013 - Is it possible to show more than 1 records using Bing Maps

Tags: bing-maps, crm, dynamics-crm-2013

In Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2013, is it possible to show more than 1 records using Bing Maps? If so, how?

Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, but this requires using the full Bing Maps API. The built in maps in CRM 2013 only support a single location. Here are some blog posts on using the full Bing Maps API in CRM 2013:

http://www.bing.com/blogs/site_blogs/b/maps/archive/2013/07/19/address-and-location-capture-in-dynamics-crm-with-bing-maps.aspx

http://www.bing.com/blogs/site_blogs/b/maps/archive/2012/11/13/create-heat-maps-with-bing-maps-and-dynamics-crm.aspx

There are also some apps in the CRM store that you could use:

http://dynamics-crm.pinpoint.microsoft.com/en-US/applications/crm2maps-free-mapping-tool-for-microsoft-dynamics-crm-12884913381

http://dynamics-crm.pinpoint.microsoft.com/en-US/applications/CRM-Call-Planner-12884940553

Answer (score 0):

I found CRM2Maps a free tool very useful. InfoGrow also has a few other really nice mapping tools for CRM. http://www.infogrowcorp.com/CRM/Customize/CRM2Maps/CRM2Maps+Download/default.aspx